# Select one value from a table and only one match from another table based on a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

I have two tables as this example

-New APP

| ActivityID | ActivityName | CreatedOn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | name1 | 2022-07-07 17:59:24.453 |
| 123333 | name2 | 2022-07-07 17:59:24.453 |
| 123123 | name3 | 2022-07-01 17:59:24.453 |
| 123123 | name4 | 2022-07-01 17:59:24.453 |

-Old APP

| ActivityID | ActivityName | CreatedOn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123123.123123.0000 | name | 2022-07-01 17:59:24.453 |
| 123123.123123.1111 | name | 2022-07-01 17:59:24.453 |
| 123123.123123.1112 | name | 2022-07-01 17:59:24.453 |

I want to find a way to get only one matching record from the Old app to only one matching record from the New APP
I tried with this

```
with cte as ( select *,row_number() over( partition by ActivityID order by ActivityID ) rn
from OldApp),
cte2, select * row_number() over( partition by left(ActivityID,6) order by left(ActivityID,6)         rn
from NewApp
)
select * from cte
right outer join cte2 on (cte.ActivityID  = cte2.ActivityID and cte.rn=1 and cte2.rn=1)
```

But the results still showing multiple values for the row number column from the cte2
What am I missing here?

Comment: Your SQL should be giving you an error because a bracket is missing: ` left(ActivityID,6)         rn
from NewApp` `over (` is not closed. Also `cte2,` should be `cte2 as (`

Comment: You'll want an inner join if you need to filter rows out.

Comment: @shawnt00 but I need all the data from the old app and only one match from the new app. The inner will show only matching records

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch the table names in the cte and join with the `LEFT` of activityID to get only row 1, but the right join will still show the other rows as well

> ```
> with cte as ( select *,row_number() over( partition by ActivityID order by ActivityID ) rn
> from NewApp),
> cte2 as ( select * ,row_number() over( partition by left(ActivityID,6) order by left(ActivityID,6) )        rn
> from OldApp
> )
> select * from cte
> right outer join cte2 on (left(cte2.ActivityID,6) = cte.ActivityID and cte.rn=1 and cte2.rn=1)
> ```
>
> ```
> ActivityID | ActivityName | CreatedOn               |   rn | ActivityID         | ActivityName | CreatedOn               | rn
> ---------: | :----------- | :---------------------- | ---: | :----------------- | :----------- | :---------------------- | -:
>     123123 | name3        | 2022-07-01 17:59:24.453 |    1 | 123123.123123.0000 | name         | 2022-07-01 17:59:24.453 |  1
>       null | null         | null                    | null | 123123.123123.1111 | name         | 2022-07-01 17:59:24.453 |  2
>       null | null         | null                    | null | 123123.123123.1112 | name         | 2022-07-01 17:59:24.453 |  3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=41c4d555533df62845fa5798a9daef99)*

> ```
> with cte as ( select *,row_number() over( partition by ActivityID order by ActivityID ) rn
> from NewApp),
> cte2 as ( select * ,row_number() over( partition by left(ActivityID,6) order by left(ActivityID,6) )        rn
> from OldApp
> )
> select * from cte
> INNER  join cte2 on (left(cte2.ActivityID,6) = cte.ActivityID and cte.rn=1 and cte2.rn=1)
> ```
>
> ```
> ActivityID | ActivityName | CreatedOn               | rn | ActivityID         | ActivityName | CreatedOn               | rn
> ---------: | :----------- | :---------------------- | -: | :----------------- | :----------- | :---------------------- | -:
>     123123 | name3        | 2022-07-01 17:59:24.453 |  1 | 123123.123123.0000 | name         | 2022-07-01 17:59:24.453 |  1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9eda572371642db851fbb762b0b07fcd)*

Comment: This is still showing row number 1,2,3. I actually need only 1 match from the right. I don't know why its not working even though its specified in the condition "and cte.rn=1 and cte2.rn=1"

Comment: @Sam332 I clearly wrote in my answer that the cause is the RIGHT JOIN and that it should be an INNER JOIN instead, as you have problems i added the inner join solution also

Comment: Sorry I might not have made it clear in my post. The reason inner join will not work is that I need all the data from the old app and only one match from the new app.

Comment: you said in your column you need one match , which my query already makes, so i don't see why my answer doesn't show what you want, it shows all rows of old table an one row of new

Comment: You see how we got "and cte.rn=1 and cte2.rn=1" My thought it should always bring rn1 from the left cte and only if there's at least one match from cte2 if that makes sense.

Comment: no right join takes all rows from old and join rows from the left table that fits as you in the foddle i don't understand what result you want istead, so plost it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246865/discussion-between-sam332-and-nbk).

Answer (score 0):

```
with new as (
    select *,
        row_number() over (partition by ActivityID order by CreatedOn, ActivityName) rn
    from NewApp
)
select * from OldApp old left outer join new
    on left(old.ActivityID, 6) = new.ActivityID and new.rn = 1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=a2852289ed3a12eab0868542706cd895